Python subprocess FILE NOT FOUND error when executing a PyInstaller generated file in Linux from a shared VOLUME under DOCKER
I have generated an executable, say,test (no extension since it's Linux) using PyInstaller and stored it in a directory, say data.
I have a Python program that is as below:
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
...
def run_exe():
    try:
        # get current directory
        currdir = Path.cwd()
        datadir = currdir / "data"
        #print(currdir)
        #print(datadir)    
        
        process = subprocess.run(["./test"], shell=False, capture_output=True, text=True, cwd=datadir)
        if(process.stderr): 
            print("stderr:", process.stderr)
            return JSONResponse(content={"success": False}, status_code=400)
        if(process.returncode == 0):
            print(process.stdout)
            return JSONResponse(content={"success": True})
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e)    
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__)  # Prints the name of the exception class
        print(e)  # Prints the exception message


I have tried the following:

Putting subprocess.run(["ls"], it shows the correct directory and files including test

Putting subprocess.run(["ls", -l"], it shows the execution permission in test

I tried moving to the parent directory and running.

I tried subprocess.run(["test"] ...) without the ./

I tried changing shell=True. Still gives an error.


With both the ls commands (2 and 3) it prints the output.
The error I get is an OSError:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './test'
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

What is the actual path of the file that it reports as not found?

The file is in the data directory and when I put ls in the run, it does show the file

If the file is in the correct place then your program must be constructing the path incorrectly. So you need to show us the actual complete path to the file, and the complete path that the program is using to access it.

Just a data point. If I put a shell script like test.sh with just an echo and run["./test.sh"] with shell=True, it works

with subprocess.popen() you have the same problem?

It does not matter how many other commands you run which work. The issue lies with your python code and its associated test program. And unless you can show the exact details of what path the test program is trying to use, we cannot guess what may be wrong.

subprocess.popen() gives the same error message

OldBoy / kithuto: Thanks for your inputs.  I will revert by making the test executable to be a simple print("hello world") and share the result here in a bit.

I just realised that I have not mentioned that I am running this in a DOCKER environment (my bad). And it so happens that data directory is a shared volume. I suspect the problem must be because of that. Let me work in that direction

I discovered that the issue was with the manner in which PyInstaller was creating the executable. Apparently, by default it uses (some) loader library that works on Linux and Windows (different executables, of course). But since Docker uses Alpine with a different loader, the error shows up.
I created the PyInstaller executables using the following link (https://hub.docker.com/r/fydeinc/pyinstaller) and it worked smoothly.
Earlier I missed mentioning DOCKER in my title or issue explanation. I will correct that just in case someone has a similar issue.
Thanks @OldBoy / @Kithuto for your quick responses.
